# How do you delete an in-memory SQLite database with PHP PDO?

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

When I create a SQLite memory database - how do I delete it when I'm finished? Is it automatically released when the script ends and closes the connection?

```
$pdo = new PDO('sqlite::memory:');
```

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html

Comment: I suspect you'd want to destroy the PDO object (`$pdo = NULL;`) to get the memory released **before** script execution ends (if you're using it in a lengthy unit testing suite, for example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's what happens.

Comment: You could append a link to an authoritative reference.

Answer (score 15):

> The most common way to force an SQLite database to exist purely in 
>   memory is to open the database using the special filename ":memory:"...
>   ...When this is done, no disk file is opened. Instead, a new database is
>   created purely in memory. The database ceases to exist as soon as the
>   database connection is closed. Every :memory: database is distinct
>   from every other. So, opening two database connections each with the
>   filename ":memory:" will create two independent in-memory databases.
>   - [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html)